# Unable to call a plugin function outside document.ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I am using jquery e JSF to build the pages of my application. After every ajax request I need to bind some functions, like masks, form messages, etc.
My problem is that outside `$(function()`, I can't access the plugins:

```
(function($) {
    // call setMask function on the document.ready event
    $(function() {
      // calling a function, the plugin is undefined.
        initMsgForm();
     // calling here, it works.
        if (typeof $.fn.areYouSure !== 'undefined') {
            $('#myForm').areYouSure({
                'message' : 'You have unsaved data'
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

function initMsgForm() {
if (typeof $.fn.areYouSure !== 'undefined') {
    $('#myForm').areYouSure({
        'message' : 'Você tem informações não salvas'
    });
}
```

}

Why can't I access the plugins inside my function?

Edit:
Both functions are in the same file "main.js"
The xhtml where I include the js files:

```
<h:head>
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title></title>
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="middle">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />

    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/dashboard.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/main.css" />

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js" />
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.6.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.are-you-sure.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/meiomask.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/main.js" />
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="last">
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.meiomask/1.1.14/meiomask.min.js" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/font-awesome.css" />
</f:facet>
```

Comment: If you don't see the plugins at that point, you're not loading them properly. This question is really too fragmentary to be usefully answered, though.

Comment: Also note: you can combine an IIFE with DOM-ready using the `jQuery(function($){YOUR CODE USING A LOCAL $ HERE});` shortcut syntax. It does both in one.

Comment: It sounds like the plugins are loaded within, or are using, DOM-ready callbacks when they shouldn't be. You need to show the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was trying to load jQuery. By default, primefaces already loads jQuery, so I was including twice. I remove the jQuery declaration, and now it works.